# Employee Bus Allocation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

My company recently started transportation for employees. We want to build an algorithm which allocates employees to a bus based on bus stop.

no. of buses and bus routes are fixed:
Ex:

```
(Capacity:40) Bus #1, ------ stop1 ----- stop3 ------- stop5 ----------    
(Capacity:50) Bus #2, ------ stop2 ----- stop3 ------- stop6 ---------- stop5    
(Capacity:40) Bus #3, ------ stop3 ----- stop4
```

No. of employees availing transportation:

```
stop1: 10,    
stop2: 10,    
stop3: 20,    
stop4: 18,    
stop5: 20,    
stop6: 10
```

How can we allocate optimal no. of employees to buses?
Is there any standard algorithm that defines a solution for this problem? I googled but couldnt find any relevant algo for this. Please guide me in the correct direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "optimal" allocation? To minimize the maximum number M of employees in a bus at any given time? If so, it sounds like we can do a binary search on M, and for fixed M (inside the loop), maybe construct some flow network (don't know exactly how for now, just an idea) and check whether the size of the maximum flow is the total number of employees. If less, we should increase M; if equal, we can try to increase it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might end up similar to the [Bin Packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), [Knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and [Cutting stock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem), although not identical. Those problems are NP-hard, so I suspect your problem is too.

1. Check if solvable: Total(employees) < Total (bus spaces)
2. For stops where only one bus serves: allocation space on that bus. (e.g. stop 1,2,4,6 in your example).

Maybe:

1. Sort stops by number of buses serving stop.
2. Allocate passengers by first fit?